# Assign a string to a string return type function without copying

Tags: c++, qt, move

I want to learn how to write efficiently(who doesn't), and I wanted my example to involve familiar and simple concepts. I'm actually using Qt, but I hope it is not a problem, since the question is quite general. I have a function that goes like this:

```
QString elide(const QString& text, int length)
{
    if (text.length() < length) 
        return text;
    
    QString elided = text.mid(0, length);
    elided.append("...");

    qDebug() << &elided[0];

    return elided;
}
```

Then I use this function to assign a string, which is a member variable:

```
void AllergiesTile::refresh()
{
    if (patient->allergies.isEmpty())
        allergies = noInfo;
    else
    {
        allergies = elide(patient->allergies, 50);
        qDebug() << &allergies[0];
    }
}
```

noInfo is a member QString variable, which is assigned to "No information", but that is not important. The thing is that when I debug the address of the first character of the string in the elide function, and the one after the assignment of allergies(incase of eliding) - they are different. So there is a copying process going on here. How to avoid it? Even if I use something like allergies = std::move(patient->allergies, 50) or return std::move(elided) in the elide function, the copying is still present.

Edit: Obviously I want to learn about the move semantics, but even in this simple example, I'm having troubles implementing them. I know that the possible performance gain if the copying is omitted will be negligible, but the question here is a matter of principles, and how things work.

Comment: Please avoid pointing out that you are new to a certain technology as it is irrelevant to your question. Here we do not focus only on the problem and not on the OP. The characteristics of the OP should not and cannot intervene in how you answer since the answers will be the same if you are an expert or a beginner.

Comment: Ain't QString a copy-on-write class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not guarantee copy elision for the way `elide()` uses `return`. This can be discussed in more detail, but it will become clear that this is going to be irrelevant. There's another, more fundamental issue at play. The bottom line is that you have no guarantee that returning from `elide()` elides the implicit copy, here.

Recent C++ standards does allow the compiler to ***optionally*** elide a copy here, but even that doesn't really help you because of what happens in the calling function:

```
allergies = elide(patient->allergies, 50);
```

This is assigning the return value from `elide()` to ***a different object***. That, in a nutshell, is something that makes a copy, of some sort *unavoidable*. It may not wind up to be an actual copy (this invokes the object's assignment operator). But some kind of a copy happens here, one way or another. As sure as the sun rising in the east, every day (except near the poles).

If, on the other hand, the returned value was used to construct ***a new object***, for example:

```
auto allergies = elide(patient->allergies, 50);
```

Now it is possible (but not guaranteed) that if the compiler elides the implicit copy when `return`ing a value from a function, then no copying will take place, and inside `elide()` this object gets effectively constructed "in place", right where `allergies` "is".

But you are ***assigning*** the returned value to an ***existing*** object. This makes all the difference in the world. The object constructed inside `elide()` ***must*** be a different object, for the obvious reasons. Ergo, there is no way to elide this copy, for fundamental reasons.

Comment: This does not mention that `allergies = elide(patient->allergies, 50);` will call the _move_ assignment operator (`QString` has one), since `elide(patient->allergies, 50)` is a prvalue. I don't know how a `QString` is implemented, but this can be way faster than a string copy, since only a couple of pointers/integers could need to be modified, without requiring the whole string contents to be copied. A copy could still be made (elision not guaranteed), but the compiler could optimize this to be O(1), as far as I can see.